# Где скачать файл vmware-mount.exe?

Tags: vmware

Мне нужен только vmware-mount.exe
Он должен быть внутри vSphere Disk Development Kit или VDDK SDK for Windows

На официальном сайте невозможно скачать.

Где скачать файл vmware-mount.exe или VDDK? Кто может загрузить куда-нибудь этот файл?

Comment: скачался файл при использования другого vpn